# Invalid Types for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having a very strange error with C++ that I can't quite make out. I've initialized hundreds of arrays before, but for some reason when I make an array of doubles:

```
double trap[]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
```

And then try to do ANYTHING with specific elements of this array, i.e.:

```
cout << trap[3] << endl;
```

I get the strange error:

```
compare.cpp:43:20: error: invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array subscript
 cout << trap[3] << endl;
```

Which I don't understand at all.  Why would the subscript(integer) have anything to do with the type of value contained in that element(double)?

EDIT: Here is my full code that is giving the error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <cmath>   
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const double Xmax[]={2.0,10.0,20.0,40.0, 80.0, 160.0};

double f (double x) { 
  return (exp(-x));               
}

int main() {
  FILE *Trap = fopen("trap.dat","w"); 

  double trap[]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0}, 

cout << gaus2_old[3] << endl;
//...do other stuff with trap[] and Xmax[]...
}
```

Where everything in the line "do other stuff with trap[] and Xmax[]" is just the rest of my code, where every instance of trap[] and Xmax[] gives the same error:

```
compare.cpp:43:20: error: invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array
```

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). "_

Comment: Your example [works correctly](https://ideone.com/JJq17I).

Comment: These two lines compile fine. The error must be somewhere else. Can you show us larger part of your code?

Comment: This code seems to work fine. Are you sure this is the line with the error?

Comment: Sorry! I added my "full" code above in an edit.  I've tried compiling this on multiple machines and I still always get the same error every time I try to call any specific element in the array.

Comment: Now, there are two errors in your code: `,` instead of `;` at the end of trap initialization and usage of undeclared variable `gaus2_old`. I fixed the first error and replaced `gaus2_old` with `trap`. It compiled with no error. Yet, even with the mistakes I mentioned, I haven't got invalid types error, only syntax error and undeclared identifier. I even tried to add more calls to `Xmax` and `trap` but it still compiles. Is it minimal portion of code that causes the problem? Also, what compiler do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I run this code in VS and it prints 0 to the console.

```
// testcpp.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double trap[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    cout << trap[3] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

On Update: I agree with https://stackoverflow.com/users/5289220/sukces-elektroniki , Change

```
double trap[]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0},
```

to

```
double trap[]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
```

AND

change

```
cout << gaus2_old[3] << endl;
```

to

```
cout << trap[3] << endl;
```

Comment: Once the question is clarified, this answer might be "stale"

Comment: Sorry! I added my "full" code above in an edit. I've tried compiling this on multiple machines and I still always get the same error every time I try to call any specific element in the array.